# How to know when does the application comes into foreground?

Tags: android, android-service

I have one service(service A) and one application (app B). I Want to perform some operations in service A every time app B comes into foreground(visible to user).
Is there any Listener/callback that will inform the service A when app B comes into foreground?
I know polling method to check the app present on top of the stack after some interval repeatedly but i want Listener/callback based solution, can anyone suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Is app B your app? Can you have app B notify the service?

Comment: No I have code access of service A only.Can not change app B code.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `bindService`, when other apps call `bindService` `onBind` inside `Service` called, through intent you know what app is binding to your Service, it means it is in forceground

Comment: I can not edit the app code.I can only edit the service code.
It means whatever implementation i wanted to do i will have to do it in service code only.